# How to verify credit card and post a sale in a single API transaction?

Tags: braintree

*edit:*

**tl;dr: you can't.**

You have to create a payment method in order to verify it. Creating a sale does NOT invoke verification, even if verification is enabled globally.

*original:*

I'm reading about [credit card verification](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/credit-cards/server-side/php#verification-results), which apparently isn't done automatically during [Braintree_Transaction::sale()](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/php), but I don't see any options to enable verification on calling sale().

Do I really have to implement (at least) two separate API transactions just to verify a credit card?

Ideally I would like to use a single call to ::sale() to perform validation, authorization, and capture.

I have already enabled verification through my control panel, and I'm using test credit card number 4000111111111115 which, is supposed to be declined, but i'm getting successful transactions with it.

Do I have to create a payment method separately in order to perform validation, even if I have global validation enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

To [test card verification](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/php#unsuccessful-credit-card-verification) results, please [adjust the amount](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/php#test-amounts) of your transaction. Because these cards are not linked to real accounts, Braintree cannot make the small [authorization charges](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/credit-cards/server-side/php#card-verification) that are made in production, and instead the API must rely on the amount of the test transaction to dictate the expected response.

In a Production environment, Card verification is triggered by the creation of payment methods, not by transactions. To enable verification, either [enable it across all payment methods](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/vault/card-verification#enabling-card-verification), or add the [`verifyCard`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/create/php#options.verify_card) option to your `PaymentMethod::Create` call. The response to `PaymentMethod::Create` in either of these cases will contain a [`creditCardVerification`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/credit-cards/server-side/php#verification-results) object if the verification fails for any reason, allowing you to stop the transaction before `sale` is called.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are you saying that Braintree_Transaction::sale() *does* trigger card validation, but only in live environment?

Comment: I have updated the answer to hopefully be a little more clear. Let me know if it doesn't answer your question!

Comment: OK, I think you're saying: even in production, I have to perform verification separately, even when verification is enabled across all payment methods. Transaction::sale() will never verify the payment method.

Comment: @jellenberger Then whats the point of using transaction.sale() If users could use fake credit card numbers.

Comment: To follow up on the comment from @Abdel , what is meant by card verification?  Are you saying it is possible to submit transactions without verifying the card?  This is pretty confusing...

Comment: According to the page linked by aaronbauman, "the gateway verifies cards by running either a $0 or $1 authorization and then automatically voiding it."  I guess that's what is meant by card verification.  I guess this doesn't have to happen automatically for transaction.sale() because the transaction itself verifies the card (though a large price could affect the result?).  @jellenberger: Is this accurate?